# i want to add custom field in django-allauth SignupForm

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

i wanted to add custom field with django-allauth SingupForm and adding new field like phone number. i already managed to add this field in Postgresql on my own(without migrations,but by my hands).
[this is my postgresql screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ackZQ.png)
In my signup page i have these fields already but i can't managed to add "phone" to my database, i really want to make it! please someone help me.

forms.py

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm 
from django import forms

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Voornaam')
    last_name  = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Achternaam')
    phone      = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='phone')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'] = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['last_name']  = forms.CharField(required=True)
        self.fields['phone']  = forms.CharField(required=True)


        
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        
        user.save()
        
        return user

        def signup(self,request,user):
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.save()
            return user
```

settings.py
`ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'registration.forms.CustomSignupForm'}`

Comment: You can't just add a field manually to the database if you then want django to manage it for you. You either need a profile model which has a relationship to users or a custom user model which contains the fields you want for your users. Then your form can talk to the model and the whole thing can add data to your database.

Comment: can you give me right directions to what you said above,i am  beginner and don't have much experience to it.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a profile model which is attached to a user so that you can add extra fields for information you might want.

*If you're starting a project from the very beginning you can also consider a custom user model so that all data is on one object.*

When I do this, I create an `accounts` app which I put my overrides in for `allauth` and my model starts something like this (modified to add the `receiver` function which I don't have at the moment because I'm not using `Profile` objects);

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


User = get_user_model()


class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata
        """
        app_label = 'accounts'
        verbose_name = _('User profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('User profiles')

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=User,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # Add your fields here like `phone`

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String representation
        """
        return f'User Profile for: {self.user}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Setup a profile as a user is created
    """
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)  # Using `create` also saves the object
```

Your signup form then does something like

```py
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.profile.phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        
        user.profile.save()
        
        return user
```

If you've already got users you'll also need a migration which creates profiles for them;

```py
# Generated by Django 2.2.12 on 2020-05-01 22:03

from django.db import migrations


def create_profiles(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model('authentication', 'User')  # this should match the User model you are using
    Profile = apps.get_model('accounts', 'Profile')

    for user in User.objects.all():
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        profile.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_profiles, migrations.RunPython.noop)
    ]
```